# JavaScript Interface not working in my Android Application

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview, local-storage

Following is my MainActivity class code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);

    //add the JavaScriptInterface so that JavaScript is able to use LocalStorageJavaScriptInterface's methods when calling "LocalStorage"
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new LocalStorageJavaScriptInterface(this), "LocalStorage");

    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    // TO enable JS
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // To enable Localstorage
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    //those two lines seem necessary to keep data that were stored even if the app was killed.
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
 /*   
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() { 
        public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize, long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) { 
                quotaUpdater.updateQuota(5 * 1024 * 1024); 
            } 
        });*/

    //load HTML File in webview
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/main.html");

    setContentView(webView);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


/**
 * This class is used as a substitution of the local storage in Android webviews
 * 
 * @author Diane
 */
public class LocalStorageJavaScriptInterface {
        private Context mContext;
        private LocalStorage localStorageDBHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase database;

        LocalStorageJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
                mContext = c;
                localStorageDBHelper = LocalStorage.getInstance(mContext);
        }

        /**
         * This method allows to get an item for the given key
         * @param key : the key to look for in the local storage
         * @return the item having the given key
         */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public String getItem(String key)
        {
                String value = null;
                if(key != null)
                {
                        database = localStorageDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                        Cursor cursor = database.query(LocalStorage.LOCALSTORAGE_TABLE_NAME,
                                        null, 
                                        LocalStorage.LOCALSTORAGE_ID + " = ?", 
                                        new String [] {key},null, null, null);
                        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
                        {
                                value = cursor.getString(1);
                        }
                        cursor.close();
                        database.close();
                }
                return value;
        }

        /**
         * set the value for the given key, or create the set of datas if the key does not exist already.
         * @param key
         * @param value
         */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void setItem(String key,String value)
        {
                if(key != null && value != null)
                {
                        String oldValue = getItem(key);
                        database = localStorageDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(LocalStorage.LOCALSTORAGE_ID, key);
                        values.put(LocalStorage.LOCALSTORAGE_VALUE, value);
                        if(oldValue != null)
                        {
                                database.update(LocalStorage.LOCALSTORAGE_TABLE_NAME, values, LocalStorage.LOCALSTORAGE_ID + " = " + key, null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                database.insert(LocalStorage.LOCALSTORAGE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                        }
                        database.close();
                }
        }

        /**
         * removes the item corresponding to the given key
         * @param key
         */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void removeItem(String key)
        {
                if(key != null)
                {
                        database = localStorageDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                        database.delete(LocalStorage.LOCALSTORAGE_TABLE_NAME,   LocalStorage.LOCALSTORAGE_ID + " = " + key, null);
                        database.close();
                }
        }

        /**
         * clears all the local storage.
         */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void clear()
        {
                database = localStorageDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                database.delete(LocalStorage.LOCALSTORAGE_TABLE_NAME, null, null);
                database.close();
        }
}
```

}

Basically I am using AndroidLocalstorage plugin https://github.com/didimoo/AndroidLocalStorage which is basically used as a fallback option to localStorage.

Following is my AndroidMainifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android_playlist"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>



    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android_playlist.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Basically the issue is that the javascriptInterface is NOT working for me.

I have added following lines of code in my js file which loads

```
try{
    //we replace default localStorage with our Android Database one
    window.localStorage=LocalStorage;    
}catch(e){
    //LocalStorage class was not found. be sure to add it to the webview
        console.log("error", e);
        console.log("LocalStorage ERROR : can't find android class LocalStorage. switching to raw localStorage")              
   }
```

But when I checked the browser console I always get the console.log which is in catch.

**Can some one please throw some light on what is wrong with my code and why the Javascript interface is NOT working for me.**

Following is the error I am getting in the console

```
{stack: (...), message: "LocalStorage is not defined"}
```

One IMP thing I forgot to mention is that I am testing this on my laptop browser by simply loading the HTML file using file: protocol. 
Does this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the issue in my code, In AndroidMainifest XML my targetSDK version was 18.
it should have been 19 as I am not setting up database path as well as database size in my MainActivity.

Original Code

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Changed Code

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="14" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.localStorage=LocalStorage;
```

above code gives meaning that window object has the property named `localStorage` and your trying set its value as `LocalStorage`. `LocalStorage` object created for you by android that can be guarantied but ultimately `localStorage` property for window object no guaranty.so the exception is thrown. Hope this ans will help you.

Comment: Are you suggesting that window has no property with name localStorage? Even before this change I was using localStorage.... so I am perplexed

Comment: I tested this code on my Samsung note Android 4.1.2, I added some items into localStorage and restarted the phone, the localStorage data wiped out :( Can someone please help me here

Comment: first set the javascript enabaled flag, then add javascript interface to the webview.

Comment: @ShantanooK  window.localStorage=LocalStorage u cannot do this. there is no attribute named localStorage in window object.

Comment: then what should I do, also I am not getting any issue accessing window.localStorage  rather the exception is that LocalStorage is NOT defined

Comment: NOT WORKING and also not a clean but dirty solution. Better do instead: var oLs = window.LocalStorage || window.localStorage; oLs.setItem( 'test', 'value' );